# Can i get detail profile of user with total reviews from amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can i get detail profile of user with total reviews from amazon? Yes I can get reviews for products as API return me with an Iframe but I need the total reviews made by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can get a customer's review for a particular product, but not sure whether you can get it for all their reviews via API.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingCustomerReviews.html

However, but every Amazon user has an ID and you can visit their profile page to see their review activity.

http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3LTZGHZBBBQX0

It will show you a list of products they have reviewed. Although scrapping such pages may be violation of copyrights/usage terms.

Shahid

Comment: Ok @Shahid  Your answer was helpful. Now according to your answer I need to have an ID of the user. So as we get amazon unique id in response to our Login with amazon. Is there a way we can get the user id A3LTZGHZBBBQX0 which is there in the link you have provided above.

Comment: I don't think you can get that from public access unless you have the user give that/login for you. Giving details on users would be a violation of privacy and security. Especially since money is involved, and many customers may have stored their card details as well.